# EditText methods in java android

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, hint

Hello I'm new to android developing.

Is there a method in java that equals to #.gotFocus?

Is there in java an events list that I can watch and select like in c# visual studio?

I tried to do #.Focus or something similar but had no success.

I want to reproduce the following scheme:

1- EditText has a certain hint => "Enter a value"

2- The user clicks the edit text and the hint disappears => ""

3- The user fills a certain value => "certain value"

Thank's for helpers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ron Yamin, If I understand your doubt correctly what you want is:

1- Have a field of text for the user to type words/numbers etc --> It is called EditText in android

2- Have an hint so the user knows what to type --> Eg. "Type your name"

3- And react to focus in some way.

The first one you will achieve either through XML or by code. If you have a main.xml in your layouts folder (assuming you are using eclipse/android studio to develop), you can use the interface to drag an edit text to the android screen.

The second one you will achieve still through the XML. If you right click on it, right side of the screen there will be a little window called Proprieties that you can change things like height and width and a hint. Type there your hint.

Finally the last one you need to go to your code in .java and get a reference of your edit text (findViewById).

Either through setOnClickListener or setOnFocusChangeListener.

More info you can checkout here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

I have googled a tutorial you can check with more detailed information and step by step guide.
Hope it helps:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/edittext/android-edittext-example/

Comment: Do you know why my function CheckBox.isSelected() doesn't work ? (I select the checkbox and it doesn't get in my if)

Comment: You want to receive an event when the user selects it, or are you checking the value indirectly ? (eg. User checks the checkbox and then clicks a button and you verify if the box is checked)

Comment: Exactly to the point. Thank you very much. If you understand in andorid and c# tcp client server you can help me in this question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675101/advanced-android-and-c-sharp-tcp-client-server

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you changed your question quite a bit, and my C# ignorance got the best of me.

It seems that what you really want is an EditText, the example text you are looking for is the hint.

You can set the hint in the xml file or by code with .setHint(string) method.

Here's where to start:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

*edit 3* - events in android are dealt with by using listeners. You can use an onClickListener to achieve what you want.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(){
     //dostuff
   }
}
```

Comment: That's no my problem, I want a function that do something when the user set focus.. see my edit please.

Comment: And it doesn't textView it TextField.

Comment: Edited it a bit, there are quite a few ways to deal with events in android, but i think what you want is an onclicklistener.

Comment: No dude.. If in the middle of typing the user click on the textedit ? I dont want it to be clear too.. just if it gotFocus from lostFocus.. look up someone answer it. Thank's anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your textfield is an instance of `EditText` (which it probably should be), you can do the following:

```
textfield.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            // this is where you would put your equivalent #.gotFocus logic
        }
    }
});
```

It's worth noting that the behavior you've described can be achieved by using [`textfield.setHint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint(java.lang.CharSequence)). The hint is text that is cleared automatically when the user selects the `EditText`. It's designed specifically for the case you describe, e.g. `textfield.setHint("Enter a Value")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with c# but I'm guessing you want event fired when edittext get focus. Try this

```
 EditText txtEdit= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
                    // do the job here when edittext get focus
        }
    }
 });
```